# Phyton ¿como evitar que una opcion de menu tkinter se ejecute dos veces?

Tags: python-3.x

'Creo el menu'

```
pr=Tk()
pr.title("Sistema Logistico")

mcostos=Menu(pr, background="#afeb84")
pr.config(menu=mcostos, background="#afeb84")
#indico cada menu principal
#como hacer que no se ejecute el command
Menu_aba=Menu(mcostos, tearoff=0, bg="#afeb84")

mcostos.add_cascade(label="Abastecimiento", menu=Menu_aba)
Menu_aba.add_command(label='Proveedores', command=lambda:Ing(pr))
Menu_aba.add_command(label='Insumos', command=lambda:Ins(pr))
Menu_aba.add_command(label='Items Tecnicos')
```

'La funcion Ing(pr) genera el frame con el ingreso de datos, botones de alta baja modificacion actualizacion y salida(pr.destroy)
pero si no cierro el frame desde el boton de salida del frame y preciono nuevamente la opcion del menu me crea todo otra vez. ¿como lo puedo evitar?'

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Si no entiendo mal lo que quieres es que ciertos items del menú se puedan ejecutar una sola vez. Para ello la opción más evidente es deshabilitar el item del menú una vez ha sido ejecutado.

El siguiente código muestra cómo podría hacerse para tu ejemplo.

```
from tkinter import Menu, Tk

pr=Tk()
pr.title("Sistema Logistico")

def Ing(pr):
    print("Ejecutado Ing()")
    Menu_aba.entryconfig("Proveedores", state="disabled")

def Ins(pr):
    print("Ejecutado Ins()")
    Menu_aba.entryconfig("Insumos", state="disabled")


mcostos=Menu(pr, background="#afeb84")
pr.config(menu=mcostos, background="#afeb84")
#indico cada menu principal
#como hacer que no se ejecute el command
Menu_aba=Menu(mcostos, tearoff=0, bg="#afeb84")

mcostos.add_cascade(label="Abastecimiento", menu=Menu_aba)
Menu_aba.add_command(label='Proveedores',  command=lambda:Ing(pr))
Menu_aba.add_command(label='Insumos', command=lambda:Ins(pr))
Menu_aba.add_command(label='Items Tecnicos')

pr.mainloop()
```

Al pinchar el item "Proveedores", se ejecuta la función `Ing()`, la cual hace lo que tenga que hacer y finalmente llama a `Menu_aba.entryconfig("Proveedores", state="disabled")` lo que inhabilita el primer item del menú `Menu_aba`. Esta inhabilitación se traduce en que la GUI lo muestra en otro estilo y ya no se puede hacer clic en él.

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias. He podido realizarlo y aplicarlo al modulo donde se encuentran todas las funciones, es decir Ing() como todas las que interactuan en ese Frame. Nuevamente Muchas Gracias